# Using ISNULL and DATEDIFF of dates to days and sum the result in select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to do a couple of iterations in the query.
I need the number of days as the result.
I have 2 types of dates (AE dates) and (IPDates). Each of them has start date and an end date
(AEStartDateTime,AEENDDateTime) and (IPStartDate , IPEndDate)

I would like to select there from the table and substract both pairs each to get 2 number of days
As the result are 2 values in days format, i want to sum them.
The main condition is these column's can be null

```
SELECT
((ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY , AEStartDateTime , AEEndDateTime)),0) 
+ (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY , IPStartDate , IPEndDate)),0)) 
as 'IPBedDays'
FROM Details
```

This does not work. Can you help

Comment: Some Sample data and desired results would be helpful. Also, what database and version are you using?

Comment: Database is SQL server 2008

Comment: What error are you getting?  I only ask because, if the 1st isnull returns 0, and the 2nd isnull returns 0, you're going to get 0.

Comment: sorry, What sample data do you need? These are just dates. Like in '20130924'. So here in this case we have 4 dates

Comment: subtract 4 dates in pair to get 2 dates in the form of days. Then sum these days. I have to check if the query returns null value for the dates.

Comment: Tiny Haitian , i get a syntax error at " ),0 " and " + ( " the entire line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some parenthesis out of place:

```
SELECT ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, AEStartDateTime, AEEndDateTime),0) + ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, IPStartDate, IPEndDate),0) as 'IPBedDays'
FROM Details
```

The last parenthesis in the chunk below came before the third argument of the `ISNULL()` (same for the other `ISNULL()` statement as well):

```
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, AEStartDateTime, AEEndDateTime))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But did not get what was wrong. Was it the Brackets. My query in my question looks same.

Comment: IT was your brackets.  One too many somewhere.   I was trying to edit it for you but Goat has the right answer for you.

Comment: Thanks  Tiny Haitian .